# SQL Update with join - cant specify TABLE_NAME in from clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm having an sql error that i can't work out. I have to update a table with a couple of joins. I tried doing it without an "in" clause, but that didnt' work. Now with the in clause, here's the query I have:

```
 UPDATE sc_module_architect 
    SET
    item_name="Print Cover Price"
    WHERE 
    item_id IN (
         SELECT a.item_id
         FROM sc_module_architect a
         LEFT JOIN sc_module_architect_category_links l on l.item_id=a.item_id
         LEFT JOIN sc_module_architect_category c on c.category_content_id=l.content_id
         LEFT JOIN sc_content sc on sc.content_id=l.content_id
         WHERE item_active=1
         AND content_name LIKE "ed_abc_print%"
         LIKE item_name LIKE "Cover Price%");
```

Now when running it I get the error

```
/* SQL Error (1093): You can't specify target table 'sc_module_architect' for update in FROM clause */
```

Can't work out why this comes up. Any ideas? Mysql 5.5

Comment: I think you can Join. The Update-Where has the limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant use table under update in subquery also simultaneously:

You need to follow below syntax:

```
update tablea JOIN tableb ..... SET columnname='yourvalue' where [....]
```

Try below:

```
update sc_module_architect as t1  LEFT JOIN  (select a.item_id
    from sc_module_architect a
    left join sc_module_architect_category_links l on l.item_id=a.item_id
    left join sc_module_architect_category c on c.category_content_id=l.content_id
    left join sc_content sc on sc.content_id=l.content_id
    where
    item_active=1
    and content_name like "ed_abc_print%"
    and item_name like "Cover Price%") as t2
    on t1.item_id=t2.itemid
    set
    t1.item_name="Print Cover Price"
```

Comment: Hi @kingfisher can you explain "You cant use table under update in subquery also simultaneously"

Comment: Means your table under update "sc_module_architect" an not be used in subquery also . mysql not allows this at the same time

Answer (score 1):

You could place all the Ids into a temporary table first then use that as the lookup in the insert

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable (item_id INT);

INSERT INTO tempTable (item_id)
SELECT a.item_id
FROM sc_module_architect a
LEFT JOIN sc_module_architect_category_links l on l.item_id=a.item_id
LEFT JOIN sc_module_architect_category c on c.category_content_id=l.content_id
LEFT JOIN sc_content sc on sc.content_id=l.content_id
WHERE
  item_active=1
  AND content_name like "ed_abc_print%"
  AND item_name like "Cover Price%";

UPDATE sc_module_architect 
SET
  item_name="Print Cover Price"
WHERE 
  item_id in (select item_id from tempTable)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are setting table sc_module_architect in sub query as 'a' then use this

```
update a 
set
item_name="Print Cover Price"
WHERE 
item_id in (select a.item_id
from sc_module_architect a
left join sc_module_architect_category_links l on l.item_id=a.item_id
left join sc_module_architect_category c on c.category_content_id=l.content_id
left join sc_content sc on sc.content_id=l.content_id
where
item_active=1
and content_name like "ed_abc_print%"
and item_name like "Cover Price%");
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the condition from the `WHERE` to a `JOIN`. (And those `left` joins seem inappropriate. I think they should be `INNER` joins):

```
UPDATE sc_module_architect AS ma
  JOIN
     ( SELECT a.item_id
         from sc_module_architect a
           left join sc_module_architect_category_links l 
             on l.item_id=a.item_id
           left join sc_module_architect_category c 
             on c.category_content_id=l.content_id
           left join sc_content sc on sc.content_id=l.content_id
       WHERE content_name LIKE 'ed_abc_print%'
     ) AS t
    ON t.item_id = ma.item_id 

  SET
    ma.item_name = 'Print Cover Price'

WHERE ma.item_active = 1
  AND ma.item_name LIKE 'Cover Price%' ;
```